# What does the "start" command exactly do

Tags: windows-7, windows

From a command prompt, some programs can launch by typing the name of the exe file, and some do not (not found), However the programs not found can be run with the `start` command. For example, see this terminal session:

```
>notepad

>wordpad
'wordpad' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

>start wordpad

>
```

So what does `start` exactly do

Comment: may have to do with the file path of wordpad "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories" if you navigate to the accessories folder in cmd prompt, then use the wordpad command it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The run command in the start menu does accept wordpad to start Wordpad. This has to do with something called `APP_PATHS` introduced in Windows 95 (see Raymond Chen's blogpost [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110725-00/?p=10073)). The start command does search APP_PATHS.

Comment: additionally, wordpad isnt really really called wordpad, its called write. drop to a cmd and just write, it will launch wordpad.

Comment: Probably the same as pbrush -> mspaint and the same sorcery involved.

Comment: BroScience, it's wordpad.exe. write.exe is just a stub launching the other one.

Comment: @Joey I think you miss the @ for ping ;)

Comment: avirk, no, it's intentional ;-). Since I don't see any *technical* need for the @ I will leave it out until SE will notify in a sane way. IRC works well without needing @s and other nonsense, for example :P

Answer (score 3):

By default if you execute cmd inside of cmd, the console window will be inherited, waiting for the created process to end.

Using `start` (that is a cmd integrated command, not an executable) you can create a process in a new console instance, being able to modify process creation options and optionally wait on the created process to end.

See also

```
start /?
```

and on TechNet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx